# Trigger react change event from appium

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I am building automation for a hybrid app where the login screen is a react web view and I do not have control over it.
The Sign-in button is disabled until something is typed in the password input field. Selenium can type in the password input but react does not recognize a change so it never enables the button.
I am using the python library for appium.

This is the HTML for the password input:

```
<input type="password" class="TextInput--textInput__271qa TextInput-mobile--textInput__jba5n PasswordInput--password__8sQc8 TextInput--hasError__2DrJ8">
```

And for the Sign in button:

```
<button class="Button--strongActionButton__154DS Button--mediumButton__Ga30r SignInScreen-mobile--signInButton__adj3k" type="submit" disabled="">Sign In</button>
```

This is how I send the text to the password input field and click the sign-in button:

```
self.driver.switch_to.context(self.driver.contexts[-1])
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys("test_user@gmail.com")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

The last action is successful but since the button is disabled so it does not do anything.

I have tried triggering JS events from appium but no luck. I have also tried enabling the button through JS but it still does not detect the value of the input.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Comment: @DebanjanB just updated it, thank you!

Comment: bit of a hack but could you try background the app using: self.driver.background_app(10) and bring back to the foreground using self.driver.execute('mobile: activateApp', { bundleId: 'bundleid' }) and see if it updates?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that *the Sign-in button is disabled until something is typed in the password input field* so once you send the *password text* within the *password* field you need to wait for the **Sign-in** button to be **clickable** inducing ***WebDriverWait*** as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC      

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am actually waiting for the element to become clickable but that never happens since react doesnt identify that there is a change in the input value

Comment: @eduardoreynoso This wasn't a _comment_ rather a well researched **answer**. How do you conclude `react doesn't identify that there is a change in the input value`?

Comment: My conclusion is because React handles their own events to trigger changes in the page. They even have a Test Utilities framework https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html that help simulate events. On my web view I see that the trigger to enable the button is when there is a change in the input. Selenium does send the keys but the input value in react does not change value